# CellForRowAtIndexPath in swift and Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

When I traverse all the cell in a tableView, In Objective-C:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"change text";
}
```

It worked, but in swift I code :

```
for index in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0))!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(index)"
    }
```

It crashed, and throws an unwrap nil error. It seems that can only get the visible cells in Swift and can get all cells in Objective-C. How to explain this?

Comment: You shouldn't explicitly call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to change cell text label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is the same. Its just that in Objective C using a nil object does not crash whereas in Swift it crashes.

You can verify this by checking if the cell is nil or not in Objective-C and putting a log. In Swift to avoid the crash use optional binding instead.

E.g. `if let cell = tableView.cellFor....`

Answer (score 2):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only return the cell if it's currently visible, that's why your code causes a crash. To loop through all visible cells, just use

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    // do something
}
```